# Inserting an element at the beginning of a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I know this question has been asked before but none of the threads I found answered my question.
This is how I declared my linked list:

```
struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct List {
    struct Node *head;
};
```

And this is how I initially wrote the function to add to the beginning of the list:

```
void(beginning(struct List list,int new)){
    struct Node *newnode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->value=new;
    newnode->next=list.head;
    list.head=newnode;
}
```

However, when I tried printing the list it didn't show the new node. Then I changed it to this to see what would happen:

```
void(beginning(struct List *list,int new)){
    struct Node *newnode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->value=new;
    newnode->next=list->head;
    list->head=newnode;
}
```

And indeed it worked. However, I don't know why. This solution was just a guess as I am not very experienced with pointers and don't really understand why this works.

Comment: You're passing the list by value, so you're modifying a copy of the list. You need to pass a `struct List *` pointer.

Comment: I see, when did the copy of the list get created? Was it here? `void(beginning(struct List list,int new))`

Comment: There is a difference between passing function arguments [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_value.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_function_call_by_reference.htm). Any good beginner's book on C should explain this difference. I have provided you with some links from an online C tutorial, but I would still recommend that you buy a good book.

Comment: Yes, that would be right. The copy was created when you called the function and passed by value, not by address like in the correct code. Funny enough I had this same issue a while back while trying to erase an element and racked my brain on it for hours.

Comment: BTW, the syntax for defining a function is `void beginning(struct List list, int new) { ... }` I've never seen it written with an extra set of parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are illustrating a problem that we all had encountered when starting to learn about pointers.

With your first function, your list is valid inside the local function, but because you do not give a pointer, everything is lost when you exit the function

```c
void beginning(struct List list,int new){
    struct Node *newnode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->value=new;
    newnode->next=list.head;
    list.head=newnode;
}
```

Thanks to the pointer you give the address of the list:

```c
void beginning(struct List *list,int new){
    struct Node *newnode=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->value=new;
    newnode->next=list->head;
    list->head=newnode;
}
```

One last thing: You do not protect your malloc, it is very important that you check that the return value of malloc is different from NULL:

```c
void beginning(struct List *list,int new){
    struct Node *newnode;
    if (!(newnode =(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node))))
       return ; // -> with error handling would be even better
    newnode->value = new;
    newnode->next = list->head;
    list->head = newnode;
}
```

Last but not least, I would recommend to use a typedef for your struct:

```c
typedef struct Node {
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
}            t_Node;
```

Declare with:

```c
t_Node *newnode;
```